# Javascript Subscribe Form Validation Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm building a basic subscribe form which uses Javascript for validation, but it's not working correctly.

My Form code is:

```
<form id="pageSubscribeForm">
    <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
        <input id="pageSubscribeName" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="Tell Us Your Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
        <input id="pageSubscribeEmail" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="Add Your Email Address" />
    </div>          
    <div class="pageSubscribeCell hidden">
        <input id="pageSubscribeSpam" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
        <div class="pageSubscribeButton">
            <div id="pageSubscribeSubmit" class="pageSubscribeAction"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the validation code is:

```
$("#pageSubscribeSubmit").click(function() {
var name = $("#pageSubscribeName").val();
var nameok = 0;
var email = $("#pageSubscribeEmail").val();
var emailok = 0;
var spam = $("#pageSubscribeSpam").val();
var spamok = 0; 
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&spam=' + spam;

if(name!='Tell Us Your Name'){
    nameok = 1
}else{
    $("#pageSubscribeName").removeClass("subscribeSuccess").addClass("subscribeError");
}

if(email!='Add Your Your Email Address'){
    emailok = 1
}else{
    $("#pageSubscribeEmail").removeClass("subscribeSuccess").addClass("subscribeError");
}

if(spam ==''){
    spamok = 1
}else{
    $("#pageSubscribeSpam").removeClass("subscribeSuccess").addClass("subscribeError");
}

if(nameok == 1 && emailok == 1 && spamok == 1){
    $('#pageSubscribeSubmit').hide();
}
```

When I click on the `submit` link I get the error class added to my Name cell but the email cell stays the same and the spam cell stays hidden. Any ideas why or how to fix?

Comment: You can certainly remove a LOT of code if you just use `placeholder="Tell Us Your Name"`

Comment: My main concern at the moment is to get the thing working!

Comment: Can you please just answer my question instead of trying to edit my whole code?

Comment: Using `click` is fine for me. I don't understand what your code means, or where to put it!

Comment: @mplungjan - I've edited the code to show where teh problem is. The first `if` (Name) works, but the other don't. Any ideas why?

Comment: `if(email!='Add Your *Your* Email Address'){` - remove the second your. I fixed my code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email field doesn't get the error class because your test is checking the wrong text (2x 'Your'):

```
if(email!='Add Your Your Email Address'){
```

You also asked why "... the spam cell stays hidden ...".  There is nothing in the code you posted which would remove the .hidden class from the div around #pageSubscribeSpam.  Assuming your .hidden class does what it suggests, then the #pageSubscribeSpam input is hidden on page load.  There is no way for a user to enter a value, so when the button is clicked, its value is still ''.  So `spamok = 1`, always - it will never get the .subscribeError class added.

Comment: Oh FFS! I've been reading those over and over for hours and haven't spotted that. Thanks for pointing that out. Yeah I noticed afterwards that the `Spam` cell actually does work correclty.

Comment: :-) Happens to everyone, when you've been staring at it too long!

Comment: Thanks again. Now to get to work on the Ajax Post scripting :-(

Answer (score 0):

To fix YOUR code, remove the second "Your" in the test

if(email!='Add Your **Your** Email Address'){

To avoid such problems I strongly suggest something like this which works

```js
$(function() {
  $("#pageSubscribeSubmit").on("click", function() {
    var name = $.trim($("#pageSubscribeName").val());
    var email = $.trim($("#pageSubscribeEmail").val());
    var spam = $("#pageSubscribeSpam").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&spam=' + spam;

    $("#pageSubscribeName").toggleClass("pageSubscribeError", name == "");
    $("#pageSubscribeEmail").toggleClass("pageSubscribeError", email == "");

    var spamok = spam == $("#pageSubscribeSpam").get(0).defaultValue; // nothing changed
    $("#pageSubscribeSpam").toggle(!spamok);

    if (spamok && $(".pageSubscribeError").length == 0) { // no errors
      $('#pageSubscribeSubmit').hide();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/subscribe.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {
          $('#pageSubscribeSubmit').slideUp();
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.pageSubscribeError { border:1px solid red }
#pageSubscribeSpam { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="pageSubscribeForm">
  <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
    <input id="pageSubscribeName" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="" placeholder="Tell Us Your Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
    <input id="pageSubscribeEmail" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="" placeholder="Add Your E-Mail Address" />
  </div>
  <div class="pageSubscribeCell hidden">
    <input id="pageSubscribeSpam" type="text" class="pageSubscribeInput" value="khujh" />
  </div>
  <div class="pageSubscribeCell">
    <div class="pageSubscribeButton">
      <div id="pageSubscribeSubmit" class="pageSubscribeAction">Submit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this code does absolutely nothing. No error classes are added and the form button doesn't appear to work or do anything when the form is filled in!

Comment: Can you please just answer me why the `Name` validation in my original form works, and `E-Mail` or `Spam` doesn't?

Comment: I may have a typo. It will show in the console. I am not near my computer for another couple of hours

Comment: No offence but I've gone back to using my origial code as it's the code I understand and feel I can work with. It's jsut the email var that isn't working correctly as shown in my updated code.

Comment: I'll take a look at both later